# Grails cache issue with forms in show.gsp (view)

Tags: forms, caching, grails, view, resources

I have this very odd issue and I've picked my code apart and taken out any caching changes that I think would cause this but it still remains.

Here is whats happening:

1. I add an Address in my app, named "q", I save it and get id 1 for
   example.
2. If I add another address names "q" (q isn't restricted to unique), then save it I get id 2.
3. If I repeat 2 I get a new item with id 3.

Here is the weird part, if I put the mouse over the Edit button for 2 or 3 it has a link to 1. If I look at the HTML generated I get this section for the form:

```
<form action="/CRM/address/delete/1" method="post" ><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" id="_method" />
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <a href="/CRM/address/edit/1" class="edit">Edit</a>
        <input type="submit" name="_action_delete" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure?&#39;);" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

If I look at the show.gsp it's just the basic code from the generated scaffold:

```
<g:form url="[resource:addressInstance, action:'delete']" method="DELETE">
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <g:link class="edit" action="edit" resource="${addressInstance}"><g:message code="default.button.edit.label" default="Edit" /></g:link>
        <g:actionSubmit class="delete" action="delete" value="${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'Delete')}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');" />
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

The controller has the following action:

```
def show(Address addressInstance) {
    respond addressInstance
}
```

When i print the addressInstance it looks like the correct one.

Does anyone have any idea why I get ID 1 instead of the proper id in this form which is on the show screen of address 2 and 3???

I've tested it in H2 and PostgreSQL, Grails 2.3.3, locally and on Heroku.

Comment: If you clear the browser cache or force a refresh, do you then get 2 or 3 in the id?

Comment: @bschipp I just tested in a different browser and I get the same wrong id. Also I know this isn't a browser issue as it was reported to me by a user who was using the app. Also when I force a refresh the wrong id still gets generated in that form.

Comment: I should note it doesn't just happen with addresses, it happens with contacts, users..ie. all my domain objects. Really odd!

Comment: That does seem really odd, perhaps try putting "_debugResources=y" on the end of your url to see if maybe the resources plugin is causing the caching somehow?

Comment: @bschipp It's still happening with that on.

Comment: hmm, maybe its something to do with your edit/show action in the controller, might be worth a shot to debug and see which model is being passed through to the gsp? Sorry i can't help more.

Comment: @bschipp I've printed the addressInstance and it's the correct one.. which is why this is so bizarre. It only happens with the fields in both objects match the same fields).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug linkGenerator cache in Grails 2.3.0-2.3.4.

I've created a Jira: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10883

You can disable the cache in your config file:
grails.web.linkGenerator.useCache = false